# Wordpress wp_customize add TinyMCE editor to textarea doesnt work properly

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, customizer

I have a little annoying problem with my litle shitty code.. I try add TinyMCE to my wp_customize but it doesnt work properly. I try click on formatselect but it doesnt show list where i can choose heading and i dont know why.. everything else work fine...

this is my custom-editor.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.wysiwyg-editor').each(function() {
        var textareaId = $(this).attr('id');

        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#' + textareaId,
            height: 150,
            plugins: 'lists',
            toolbar: 'formatselect | bold italic underline bullist numlist',
            menubar: false,
            valid_elements: '*[*]',
            setup: function(editor) {
                editor.on('change', function() {
                    editor.save();
                    var content = $('#' + textareaId).val();

                    if (content.indexOf('<p>') === -1) {
                        content = '<p>' + content + '</p>';
                    }

                    content = content.replace(/<p>(\s|&nbsp;)*<\/p>/g, '<br>');

                    $('#' + textareaId).val(content);
                    $('#' + textareaId).trigger('input');
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And this is my function.php

```
function add_custom_header( $wp_customize ) {

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'header_content', array(
        'title'    => __( 'Treść' ),
        'panel'    => 'header_panel',
        'priority' => 10,
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'header_content_header', array(
        'default'   => '',
        'transport' => 'refresh',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( 'header_content_header_control', array(
        'label'       => __( 'Nagłówek' ),
        'section'     => 'header_content',
        'settings'    => 'header_content_header',
        'type'        => 'textarea',
        'input_attrs' => array(
            'class'           => 'wysiwyg-editor',
            'textarea_rows'   => 5,
        ),
    ) ); 
       
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'add_custom_header' );
```

I dont know how can i fix it. I use newest wordpress if that information helps